# Prepend label with zf2 form annotations on form element text

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, annotations, doctrine

I have a problem prepending a label to a form element with type text.

I tried this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
 *
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true" })
 * @Annotation\AllowEmpty(allowEmpty=false)
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"id": "username"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Username", "label_options":{"position":"Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormLabel::APPEND"})
 */
protected $username;
```

and this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=false)
 *
 * @Annotation\Type("Zend\Form\Element\Text")
 * @Annotation\Required({"required":"true" })
 * @Annotation\AllowEmpty(allowEmpty=false)
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StripTags"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"id": "username"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Username", "label_options":{"position":"Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormRow::LABEL_PREPEND"})
 */
protected $username;
```

But both annotations rendering the label in front of the input. Does somebody know how to enable the rendering after the input?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't use annotations however I would have thought the position option should be the literal string 'prepend' or 'append' rather that referencing the constants `LABEL_PREPEND` as this will not get resolved.